# CodeIgniter Stomp not found using composer

Tags: php, codeigniter, composer-php, stomp

So ... i'm using codeigniter3 with PHP7.0 because this is the compatible version with stomp v2.0.0 @ pecl ... everything should be in order.

I have set in application/config.php

```
$config['composer_autoload'] = TRUE;
```

In composer.json

```
{
    "name": "gritnet/gms",
    "description": "GMS is a basic content management system based on CodeIgniter with the sole purpose of helping in the development of small to medium custom websites",
    "type": "project",
    "require": {
        "rmccue/requests": "^1.7",
    "stomp-php/stomp-php": "4.*"
    },
    "authors": [
        {
            "name": "GRITNET LIMITED",
            "email": "office@gritnet.uk"
        }
    ]
}
```

On running command `composer install` i get

```
Loading composer repositories with package information
Installing dependencies (including require-dev) from lock file
Nothing to install or update
Generating autoload files
```

On running command `composer update` i get

```
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Nothing to install or update
Generating autoload files
```

When I try to connect to the server with the library I installed via composer I get the following error:

```
An uncaught Exception was encountered

Type: Error

Message: Call to undefined method Stomp::connect()

Filename: /home/gritnet/public_html/gms/application/controllers/Homepage.php

Line Number: 11
```

Line 11 is

```
        Line 10: $stomp = new Stomp('tcp://localhost:61613');
        Line 11: $stomp->connect();
```

Any idea why is not loading the class?

All the files are in **application/vendor**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Forgot to load stomp extension into php.ini file @ cPanel.
Extension can be found here: https://pecl.php.net/package/stomp